# Как найти следующее свободное значение в массиве (цифру)?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
var arr = [1,2,4,5];
```

как найти следующее свободное значение (не индекс элемента, а именно значение), то есть узнать цифру "3".

К примеру в таком массиве

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11];
```

будет свободная цифра "7"

!!! Узнать следующее (!!! НЕ все свободные), а именно ближайшее следующее свободное значение "цифру"...

Как узнать?

Помоги пожалуйста, а то уже голова устала самому думать =)

Comment: Опишите в вопросе, что вы подразумеваете под понятием "следующее свободное значение". Следующее относительно чего? начала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function closeFree(arr) {
  var closerFree = null;
  for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] - arr[i-1] > 1) return closerFree = arr[i] - 1;
  }
}
```

Работает только с **цифрами**: суть том, что мы вычитаем из текущего элемента, предыдущий, и если разница больше одного, значит между ними пропасть.

Плюс в том, что функцию можно расширить:

1. Сейчас считается от начала, можно сделать, так что бы считалось от нужного элемента вперед ( и даже назад )
2. Можно сделать возможность задать шаг, который определять, пропущен элемент или нет

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а вот если будет в массиве [1,2,5] то вернет 4, а как сделать, что бы вернуло 3 ? и массив может быть такой [1,7,17]? должно вернуть 2

Comment: уже разобрался изменил return closerFree = arr[i] - 1;   на   return closerFree = arr[i-1] + 1;

Answer (score 0):

В моём ответе обработаны дополнительные кейсы:

1. когда массив пуст
2. когда все значения в массиве идут без пропусков

```js
function closeFree(arr) {
  let freeNumber = null;
  
  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] - arr[i - 1] > 1) freeNumber = arr[i - 1] + 1;
  }
  
  return (freeNumber ? freeNumber : (arr.length ? arr[arr.length - 1] + 1 : 1));
}

console.log(closeFree([])); // 1
console.log(closeFree([1, 2, 3, 6, 7])); // 4
console.log(closeFree([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7])); // 5
console.log(closeFree([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])); // 8
```